# Typesafe Activator 0.3.0 Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:8888

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, typesafe-stack, typesafe, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to use typesafe-platform and when I run command **activator ui** I get this Exception:

> C:\activator-0.3.0>activator ui
>   Found previous process id: 7552
>   Play server process ID is 3828
>   [info] play - Application started (Prod)
>   Oops, cannot start the server.

```
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:8888
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:129)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:229)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:261)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:260)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:260)
        at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(UIMain.scala:107)
        at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.app`enter code here`ly(UIMain.scala:107)
        at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.apply(UIMain.scala:107)
        at activator.UIMain.withContextClassloader(UIMain.scala:179)
        at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:107)
        at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:86)`enter code here`
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

But there is no process using 8888 port.

I'm Using Windows 8 Pro with JDK 1.7 Update 25 64 Bits

I'm using Play 2.1.3 in PATH Evironment Variable

Anyone had this problem?

Thanks

Comment: If there is nothing listening on port `8888` then perhaps you have some security / virus software blocking Activator from binding to that port.    Possible?

Comment: Hi James Ward,

Thanks for your awnser, but I discover the problem...
When you plug your Windows Phone 8 under USB port many processes of IpOverUsbSvc.exe are created using many diferent ports (including 8888).

Using the comand
**netstat -a** I couldn't find this process, but using **netstat -anb**. I found It.

Thanks

Comment: Oh wow.  I guess we should consider changing our default port.  Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: @JamesWard I ran into this same problem because the DataStax OpsCenter for Cassandra also uses port 8888 on localhost. +1 for changing the default to something less likely to conflict.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can now override the default port using the `http.port` Java param.  So to launch the UI on port `9999` do:

```
activator -Dhttp.port=9999 ui
```

Comment: Thanks! James. I was trying to run Kafka-web-console on different port, but couldn't find the appropriate parameter name and http.port worked.